# expanded in tree node not working primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

i have already record saved in database i want that when i click on update button, it get record from database and show that record by default selected and expanded, and also show all other records but not selected and not expanded,

Here is My Model code:

```
 public TreeNode getSelectedEmpMarketsForUpdate(int moID) {

    ConnectionHandler conHandler = ConnectionHandler.getConnectionHandler();
    Connection con = conHandler.getConnection();

    Statement stmt = null;
    ArrayList<MarketBean> list = new ArrayList<MarketBean>();
    TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(1, "Root"), null);
    root.setExpanded(true);

    try {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String selectQry = " select x.*,y.market_id as selected_id from (\n"
                + "select a.name as COUNTRY_NAME,a.id as COUNTRY_ID,b.name as ZONE_NAME, b.id as ZONE_ID, c.name as REGION_NAME, \n"
                + "C.ID as REGION_ID, d.name as CITY_NAME, D.ID AS CITY_ID, e.name as AREA_NAME, E.ID AS AREA_ID,f.name as MARKET_NAME, \n"
                + "F.ID AS MARKET_ID, concat(a.name,concat(b.name,concat(c.name,concat(d.name,concat(e.name,f.name))))) as completeName  \n"
                + "from country a left outer join zone b on a.id=b.country_id left outer join region c on b.id=c.zone_id \n"
                + "left outer join city d on c.id=d.region_id left outer join area e on d.id=e.city_id \n"
                + "left outer join market f on e.id=f.area_id \n"
                + "where a.name like '%%' OR b.name like '%%' OR c.name like '%%'  OR d.name like '%%' OR e.name like '%%' \n"
                + "OR f.name like '%%') x\n"
                + "\n"
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN\n"
                + "(select F.ID AS MARKET_ID\n"
                + "  from country a left outer join zone b \n"
                + " on a.id=b.country_id \n"
                + " left outer join region c \n"
                + " on b.id=c.zone_id \n"
                + " left outer join city d \n"
                + " on c.id=d.region_id \n"
                + " left outer join area e \n"
                + " on d.id=e.city_id \n"
                + " left outer join market f \n"
                + " on e.id=f.area_id  \n"
                + " right join mo_market_bridge mb on mb.`MARKET_ID` = f.`ID`\n"
                + " where mb.`MO_ID` = '" + moID + " ' ) y\n"
                + " ON y.market_id=x.market_id";

        System.out.println(selectQry);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectQry);

        TreeMap<String, TreeNode> tm = new TreeMap<String, TreeNode>();
        TreeNode country = null;
        TreeNode zone = null;
        TreeNode region = null;
        TreeNode city = null;
        TreeNode area = null;
        TreeNode market = null;
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {

            System.out.print(rs.getString("completeName"));

            if (rs.getString("COUNTRY_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("CN" + rs.getString("COUNTRY_ID"))) {
                country = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("COUNTRY_ID"), rs.getString("COUNTRY_NAME")), root);

                tm.put("CN" + rs.getString("COUNTRY_ID"), country);
                if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                    country.setExpanded(true);
                    country.setSelected(true);
                }

            }
            if (rs.getString("ZONE_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("ZN" + rs.getString("ZONE_ID"))) {
                zone = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("ZONE_ID"), rs.getString("ZONE_NAME")), country);

                tm.put("ZN" + rs.getString("ZONE_ID"), zone);
                if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                    zone.setExpanded(true);
                    zone.setSelected(true);

                }

            }

            if (rs.getString("REGION_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("RG" + rs.getString("REGION_ID"))) {
                region = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("REGION_ID"), rs.getString("REGION_NAME")), zone);
                tm.put("RG" + rs.getString("REGION_ID"), region);
                if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                    region.setExpanded(true);
                    region.setSelected(true);
                }

            }

            if (rs.getString("CITY_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("CT" + rs.getString("CITY_ID"))) {
                city = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("CITY_ID"), rs.getString("CITY_NAME")), region);

                tm.put("CT" + rs.getString("CITY_ID"), city);
                if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                    city.setExpanded(true);
                    city.setSelected(true);
                }

            }

            if (rs.getString("AREA_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("AR" + rs.getString("AREA_ID"))) {
                area = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("AREA_ID"), rs.getString("AREA_NAME")), city);

                tm.put("AR" + rs.getString("AREA_ID"), area);
                if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                    area.setExpanded(true);
                    area.setSelected(true);

                }

            }

            if (rs.getString("MARKET_NAME") != null && !tm.containsKey("MK" + rs.getString("MARKET_ID"))) {
                if (!rs.getString("MARKET_NAME").contains("MARKET")) {
                    String marketname = rs.getString("MARKET_NAME") + " MARKET ";
                    market = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("MARKET_ID"), marketname), area);

                    tm.put("MK" + rs.getString("MARKET_ID"), market);
                    if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                        market.setExpanded(true);
                        market.setSelected(true);

                    }

                } else {
                    market = new DefaultTreeNode(new BasicBean(rs.getInt("MARKET_ID"), rs.getString("MARKET_NAME")), area);

                    tm.put("MK" + rs.getString("MARKET_ID"), market);
                    if (rs.getBoolean("selected_id")) {
                        market.setExpanded(true);
                        market.setSelected(true);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        conHandler.freeConnection(con);
    }

    return root;
}
```

here is xhtml:

```
<p:tree value="#{marketMappinBean.allMarketsRoot}" 
                        selectionMode="checkbox"
                        selection="#{marketMappinBean.selectedNode}"
                        dynamic="true"
                        var="node" id="treeNode"  animate="true" highlight="true" style="width: auto "
                        >

                    <p:treeNode    >
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
```

here is bean:

```
 MarketMappingModel db = new MarketMappingModel();
    selectedMarketsroot = db.getSelectedEmployeeMarketsTree(moID);
```

by default selected and expanded not working, but all records are showing

Comment: MarketMappingModel db = new MarketMappingModel();
 allMarketsRoot = db.getSelectedEmpMarketsForUpdate(crb.getEmpID());
bean class code

Comment: So it works if you populate a model with plain java fixed/static (nested) lists instead of retrieving from a database? And you can edit your question and add the additional info in it

Comment: my requirement is that, when i am adding new record in database  data i am saving in database with employee name, it works fine, but i want to update that record so when i click on update button, it fetch the record from database and show,  but the data which i selected when saving new record now on fetching time is should be expanded and selected.